# i am getting override method issue in compute_public_path' for module `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing migration rails 3.0.5 to 3.2.3 and also changed ruby
versions from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3.

I want override the method
compute_public_path(ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper).

Now i got this  error while migrating the application (3.2.3).

`alias_method': undefined method`compute_public_path' for module
`ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper' (NameError)

Please give me your valuable suggestions the above issue.

I have done small program. it is working perfectly.

```
class String

   alias_method :old_to_s, :to_s

   def to_s
       if  self=="one"
         "coming if "
       else
        "coming else"
       end

   end


end

str = String.new("one")
p str.to_s

p str.old_to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

as of rails 3.1, the method lives in `ActionView::AssetPaths` class

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/AssetPaths/compute_public_path